# "Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." on LOCAL page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML form that I'd like to format using Bootstrap styles.  Styles only, no Javascript (yet).  I'm running this locally, not on any server, since it shouldn't need a server yet.  The page in question already has some extensive styling that I wrote myself, in a separate stylesheet.

I put some Bootstrap styles into my HTML, then included a link to the bootstrap.min.css stylesheet in the HTML page.  Result?  The Bootstrap styles won't load -- and on top of that, some of my own styles, which load before the Bootstrap stylesheet, stop working.  When I disable the link to Bootstrap.min.css, my own styles work again.

When the link to Bootstrap.min.css is enabled, I get this error:

> Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
>   resource. Resource URL: file:///[local-path]/bootstrap.min.css Source
>   Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

How do I fix this error?  How do I get my own styles to work properly when I include bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: did you try to put your css after loading the bootstrap css ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Arun.  Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference that i could see.

Comment: Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to put a working example of the problem you are facing?

Comment: I found the answer to the "source map error": I didn't have the source map file in my css folder.  However, I am no closer to figuring out why Bootstrap.css screws up my styling when I'm not referring to any Bootstrap styles in the affected tags.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to happen when `bootstrap.min.css.map` is not in the same folder as `bootstrap.min.css`.

Try to include the .map file in the same folder.